# Replacing values in column X with values from column Y, but only if the values of X match the values in column Z

Tags: r

I have two data frames, one with 1 column (X), and the other with 2 columns (Y & Z):

Column X contains numbers 1:99, but occasionally has some letters instead of numbers, ie: `1, 2, 3, A, 5, B, 7, 8, C, D, 11, 12 etc.`

Column Y contains these same letters, which are paired (as appearing in column Z) to certain numbers, ie:

`A 4`

`B 6`

`C 9`

`D 10`

How can I replace the letters in column X with the values of column Z, according to whether the letters in column X match with the letters in column Y?  This would result in column X being `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 etc.`

A straightforward `merge` won't work (I need to retain all values in X) and I'm not sure how I can use `sub` conditionally.  Also, column Y and Z contain more rows than needed for column X, so I can't just use `cbind`.  I'm not very skilled at using `regex`, although that is probably my best bet...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use a for loop. Creating your data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(X = c("A", 5, "B", 7, 8, "C", "D", 11, 12))
df2 <- data.frame(Y = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                  Z = c(4, 6, 9, 10))
```

We need to make sure things are character vectors, not factors, for testing equality

```
df1$X <- as.character(df1$X)
df2$Y <- as.character(df2$Y)
```

Then we can do the replacing:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df2)) {
    df1$X[df1$X == df2$Y[i]] <- as.character(df2$Z[i])
}
```

Finally, I'm guessing you want the `X` as numeric now that all the letters are gone:

```
df1$X <- as.numeric(df1$X)
```

Comment: You could also use `match` instead of the for loop, like this: `tmp <- df2$Z[match(df1$X, df2$Y)]; df1$X <- ifelse(is.na(tmp), df1$X, tmp)`

Comment: The `for` loop seems to work, but with 30.000 rows it is taking very long.  I extracted the rows of column X that need replacing using `grep`, but how could I incorporate this list of row numbers in the `for` loop so it only loops over those rows?    Edit: `match` works quickly and perfectly! (that is, if I enclose the second mention of `df1$X` in `as.character()`)

Comment: The for loops will be *much* faster if you take the columns out of the data frame and just use them as vectors.

Answer (score 2):

How about `X[X==Y] <- Z[X==Y]`  ?  Or, calling your Y,Z dataframe `DF` ,

`X[X==DF$Y] <- DF$Z[X==DF$Y]`

Edit: this is essentially the same as Shuja's answer, but there's no need for a loop so far as I can see.

Comment: Won't the differing lengths keep this from working? "Also, column Y and Z contain more rows than needed for column X"...

Comment: I think it'll stop at the max index of `X` .  Can't test it until I get to a machine w/ R resident :-(

Comment: or, at worst, `xmax<-length(X); X[X==DF$Y[1:xmax] ...` will take care of the mismatched lengths problem